# Does DBeaver support IDAA query acceleration?

Tags: db2, dbeaver, db2-zos

I'm currently using SQuirrel SQL for queries on DB2 with query acceleration turned on (IBM IDAA).
I found DBeaver recently and I really like it and love it.
I tried to execute a query on DB2 with it, but I don't think it supports query acceleration. Can someone confirm that this works?

I had to manually load the IBM DB2 drivers to get DBeaver work with our server (db2jcc.jar - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866).
Just in case it's a driver issue.

This is the SQL query:

```
SET CURRENT QUERY ACCELERATION = ALL;
SELECT * FROM SALES.SALES_PRODUCTS WITH ur;
```

The query executes in SQuirrl in few miliseconds, while in DBeaver it takes minutes. The same as if the query were set to `ACCELERATION = NONE;` in SQuirrl.

Comment: By searching trough IBM documentation, I found a way to use IDAA if I modify the connection string parameters; specialRegisters=CURRENT QUERY ACCELERATION=ELIGIBLE; But this means, I'm always tring to use IDAA for each query right?

Comment: To anwser my own question; It uses IDAA if it exists, otherwise it uses the query without IDAA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me is to set the additional parameters in the connection string.

specialRegisters=CURRENT QUERY ACCELERATION=ELIGIBLE;

found here https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038078

[image]